# C - Why I'm getting a segfault when I'm trying to read a char what contains backslash?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, char, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to read a file line by line and my code looking for backslashes, but when it finds one, it exits with segfault. I'm using gcc on Ubuntu linux 19.04 and C11.

```
void test(char **array) {
    boolean a = *array[0] == '\\';
    boolean b = *array[2] == '\\';
    boolean c = *array[1] == '\\';  //I get segfault here.
}

int main() {
    FILE *messages = fopen("messages.json", "r");
    char *array = NULL;
    size_t size;
    getline(&array, &size, messages);
    test(&array);  //array contains "{\n" string here.
}
```

Comment: @Fredrik I thought the same, but it turns out that `getline` allocates the buffer if both the character pointer and size are zero (isn't true in this case). Maybe in his case the implementation checks only if the char pointer is zero and still allocates everything by chance.

Comment: what is `boolean`?  Even if the header file: `stdbool.h` is included, the defined names are `true` `false` `bool`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're treating `array` as if it points directly to an array, which it doesn't.  It points to a pointer which points to an array.  You can fix it by changing `*array[i]` to `(*array)[i]`:

```
void test(char **array) {
  boolean a = (*array)[0] == '\\';
  boolean b = (*array)[2] == '\\';
  boolean c = (*array)[1] == '\\';
}
```

Comment: I agree that this is most probably the issue here. Aside from that, it's a bit dangerous to believe that the buffer is big enough to test for those characters. If the line contains less than the number of characters than he expects, it may also crash. There may be even no memory allocated at all.

Comment: @E.vanPutten Right, there are other problems, but this looks like test code.  It should really check the values in sequence, checking for `'\0'` at each point before looking further.

Comment: @E.vanPutten I've just used this code to isolate the problem. That's why the method named test. Obviously, in the real code, I'm checking the size of the array to prevent indexing out of range.

Comment: @Adrián Sopár, `size` should have initialized to `0` even in your test code, so that error probably exists in your "real" code too.

Comment: @ikegami It's true. I'm new to C. Thank you for your remark. What could be the problem if I'm not initializing the size to zero and why?

Comment: Because the documentation says that both should be zero. Some platforms might check for this and not allocate the buffer for instance. We don't know, but let's not risk it ;-)